# Traffic and access control solution for AJAX communication with Elasticsearch?

Tags: php, ajax, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

### **Situation:**

For a web shop, I want to build paged product lists - and filters on these lists - using Elasticsearch. I want to bypass the PHP/MySQL server on which the application runs entirely and communicate with Elasticsearch directly from the customer's browser through AJAX calls. Advantages are:

- A large portion of the load on the PHP/MySQL server will be handled by the ES cluster instead
- CDN opportunities (scaling!)

### **Problem:**

This approach would take a massive load off of our backend server but creates a few new issues. Anonymous users will generate lots of requests but we need some control over those:

*Traffic control:*

- How to defend against malicious users making lots of calls and scanning/downloading our entire product catalogue that way? (e.g. competition scraping pricing information)
- How can I block IP's that have been identified (somehow) as behaving badly?

*Access control:*

- How to make sure the frontend can only make the queries we want to allow?
- How to make sure customers only see a selection of the result fields and can't get any data out of ES that's not intended for them?

It's essential not to have a single machine somewhere taking care of all this cause this would just recreate a single machine responsible for handling everything. I want to take real advantage of the ES cluster without having any middleware that has to deal with the scaling issue as well.

We don't want to be fully dependent on a 3rd party, we're looking for a solution that has some flexibility regarding the partners we're working with (e.g. switch between elastic and AWS).

### **Possible solutions or partial solutions:**

I've been looking at a few 'Elasticsearch as a service' options but I'm not confident about their quality or even if I can solve the issues mentioned with them:

- www.elastic.co/found, their premium solution has a 'shield' service which does not seem to cover all of the cases mentioned above (only IP blocking as far as I can tell), but there is a custom plugin (https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard) that can do filtering on result fields and provides a way to do user management etc. This seems like a reasonable option but it is expensive and ties the application to the 'found' product. We should be able to switch partners should the need arise.
- Amazon AWS Elasticsearch service has basic IAM support and it's possible to put CloudFront in front of it but does not provide any access control.
- Installing a separate L7 application filtering solution for detecting scrapers etc.

### **Question:**

Is there anyone out there who has this type of approach working and found a good setup that tackles all of these issues?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/index.html), a commercial product created by the folks at Elastic. It should take care of most of the controls you would like to set up.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would recommend is restrict access to your elastic search instance from behind a security group and only allow the application servers IP address access on ports 22, 80, 9200, and 9300 which are the ports used by ElasticSearch.

As for protecting against scrapping there is no absolute solution for protection however if your aim is to simply limit the load these scrappers put on your application server and ES instance you can take a look at https://github.com/davedevelopment/stiphle which is aimed at rate limited users, the exmaple they use on their page is limiting to 5 requests a second which would seem very reasonable for the average user and could be lowered even further if need be to make scrapping a time consuming effort.